# How to complete this proof of commutativity with `replace`?

Tags: functional-programming, proof, agda, idris

On [this](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/proofs/patterns.html) documentation, it is mentioned how `replace` could be used to complete the proof, but it ends up using `rewrite`, which seems to be a syntax sugar that writes `replace` for you. I'm interested in understanding how to use it explicitly.

If I understand correctly, it could be used to rewrite `S k = S (plus k 0)` as `S (plus k 0) = S (plus k 0)`, given a proof that `k = plus k 0`, which would then be provable by reflexivity. But if we instance it as `replace {P = \x => S x = S (plus k 0)} {x = k} {y = plus k 0} rec`, we'll now need a proof of `S k = S (plus k 0)`, which is what we wanted to prove to begin with. In short, I'm not sure what exactly `P` should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it is fairly obvious in retrospect. If we let:

```
P = \x => S x = S (plus k 0)
```

Then, we can prove it for `x = (plus k 0)` (by reflexivity). Now, if we let `y = k`, then, by using `replace`, we gain a proof of `S k = S (plus k 0)`, which is what we need. Or, in other words:

```
plusCommZ : (m : Nat) -> m = plus m 0
plusCommZ Z = Refl
plusCommZ (S k) = replace 
  {P = \x => S x = S (plus k 0)}
  {x = plus k 0}
  {y = k}
  (sym (plusCommZ k))
  Refl
```

Completes the proof. We could do it the other way around with `P = \x => S x = S k`.

Comment: Now, how replace is justified is a mystery to me (yes, I've seen the definition).

Comment: `sym` is not really necessary here: `replace {P = \x => S k = S x} (plusCommZ k) Refl` (this is essentially `cong (plusCommZ k)`)